# PHP form submit gives me a white page with no success message

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Im working on a php script that adds data to a mysql table there are 4 fields all of which i would like required, I think i got the majory of the code correct being that i copied the code from a php book then made some changes to reflect what i was looking for for my particular srcipt but when i go to test the submit function it just gives me a white screen instead of a success/error message, im kinda stumped as to where to go from here. below is a copy of my code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//input validation all required
if (!empty($_POST['airport_name'])) {
$an = trim($_POST['airport_name']);
if (!empty($_POST['airport_code'])){
$ac = trim($_POST['airport_code']);
if (!empty($_POST['airport_lat'])){
$alat = trim($_POST['airport_lat']);
if (!empty($_POST['airport_long'])){
$along = trim($_POST['airport_long']);

//if (!empty($_POST['airport_name'])){

//$an  = trip($_POST['airport_name']);


require('/../mysqli_connect.php');
$q = 'INSERT INTO airports (airport_name, airport_code, airport_lat, airport_long) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $an, $ac, $alat, $along);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1) {
  echo '<p>The airport has been added!</p>';
  $_POST = array();
} else {
  $error = 'The new airport could not be added to the database!';
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($dbc);




} //if airport lat
   else{
     $error = 'Please enter airport lat';
   }
}   //if airport lat
else{
  $error = 'Please enter airport latitude';
}
}  //if airport code
else {
  $error = 'Please enter an airport code';
}
}  //if airport name
else {
  $error = 'Please enter an airport name';
}
} // end of submission if
if (isset($error)) {
  echo '<h1>Error!</h1>
  <p stlye="font-weight: bold; color: #COO">'. $error . 'Please try again</p>';
}

?>
<h1>Add Airport</h1>
<form action="add_apt.php" method="post">
<fieldset><legend>Fill out the for to and and airpot:</legend>
<p><b>Airport Name:</b><input type="text" name="airport_name" size="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['airport_name'])) echo $_POST['airport_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Airport Code:</b><input type="text" name="airport_code" size="4" maxlegnth="4" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['airport_code'])) echo $_POST['airport_code']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Airport Lat:</b><input type="text" name="airport_lat" size="10" maxlegnth="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['airport_lat'])) echo $_POST['airport_lat']; ?>"/></p>
<p><b>Airport Long:</b><input type="text" name="airport_long" size="10" maxlegnth="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['airport_long'])) echo $_POST['airport_Long']; ?>"/></p>
</fieldset>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Add Airport"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the errors i get when i emabled errors
Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 30

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 31

Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 39

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/add_apt.php on line 40

Mysqli_connect.php script

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DB_USER', '******_******');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '******_gateway');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
 ?>
```

Comment: Top tip, indent your code... it's practically impossible to read in that format.

Comment: often when it gives you a white page it's a php error that stop the normal flow of the page: add @ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); on top of the page to see what could be the problem.

Comment: In your insert statement the column count doesn't match the value count.

Comment: @user1537210: OK, you won't be seeing the mysqli_connect error at the moment because of the `@` symbol preceding the function call. That supresses any errors. Remove it (so that it reads `mysqli_connect(DBHOST... etc)`) and you should then be shown any errors that occur on the connection. Post those if there are any, or let us know if there are none.

Comment: @user1537210: In that case you need to check that the file is being included correctly from the main script. Replace the line `require('/../mysqli_connect.php');` with `if (is_file('/../mysqli_connect.php')) { echo '<p>The connection file is there.</p>';require('/../mysqli_connect.php'); } else { echo '<p>The connection file is not there</p>'; }` and post the results

Comment: @user1537210: Great stuff! In that case, i'll add the include stuff to my answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to find what the error is, even without using display_errors. In the part of the script where you are building and executing your query, you should change it to the following:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $an, $ac, $alat, $along);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1) {
        echo '<p>The airport has been added!</p>';
        $_POST = array();
    } else {
        $error = 'The new airport could not be added to the database!';
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
else {
    echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($dbc).'</p>';
}
```

By doing this, you are getting any MySQL errors that are occurring in your query.  In this case, the error being generated is:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Looking closer at the code, this error is occurring because you are trying to add 4 fields `(airport_name, airport_code, airport_lat, airport_long)`, but you have 5 placeholders in your SQL statement `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, so remove one of the placeholders and it will now work.

EDIT: In response to the comments in your question and this answer, also check that the connection file is being correctly included in your main script.

Comment: I tried removeing one of the placeholders and i did not do anything. I posted the errors i got when i enabled the show errors code. Also would it matter if i have an Id column in the airports table on my sql database would that mess up my script if that was not accounted for?

Comment: @user1537210: First, it doesn't matter that you don't have an id field. I tested it without one and got it working correctly. As for the errors, they indicate that the `$dbc` variable isn't a valid mysqli parameter, so the mysqli_connect that I presume is in your `mysqli_connect.php` file isn't working correctly. Can you post the contents of that?